# Direct 'file' download with Angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, file, download

Is it possible to do a direct json zip file download from angular? For example like using file:/// protocol?

Otherwise, I am aware of other approaches using Blob. But trying to find out if a direct download is possible?

**HTML**

```
<button pButton icon="pi pi-download" [label]="'Download'" (click)='directFileDownload()'></button>
```

**Typescript**

```
  directFileDownload() {
    window.location.href = 'file:///Downloads/test.json';
  }
```

`ERROR TypeError: "Access to 'file:///Downloads/test.json' from script` denied."

Comment: Should I take it its not at all possible? thanks